# OR-Tools: 0-1 klapsack with constraint on item source

Tags: python, optimization, constraints, knapsack-problem, or-tools

I am trying to do a 0-1 knapsack optimization with constraint on the source of items. I took the example from the ortools website ([ortool example](https://developers.google.com/optimization/bin/multiple_knapsack)) and try to add a constraint to only be able to pick one item from each owner in the knapsack.

I have a list of items with associated weights (data['weights']), values (data['values']) and source (data['owns']). I would like to find the best combination of items to put in knapsack knowing that only one item per source can go in the knapsack.

I am not sure how to write the constraint.

If you look at the code below and have 1 knapsack, then the optimal solution should be to take at most 1 item from owner 0, one from owner 1 and one from owner 2 which follows the weight constraint and the uniqueness of item picked (weight below 100).

Here is the code I use (taken from the ortool multiple knapsack example):

```
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp


def create_data_model():
    """Create the data for the example."""
    data = {}
    data['weights'] = [48, 30, 42, 36, 36, 48, 42, 42, 36, 24, 30, 30, 42, 36, 36]
    data['values'] = [10, 30, 25, 50, 35, 30, 15, 40, 30, 35, 45, 10, 20, 30, 25]
    data['owns'] = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    data['owners'] = list(range(3))
    data['items'] = list(range(len(data['weights'])))
    data['num_items'] = len(data['weights'])
    data['bins'] = []
    data['bin_capacity'] = 100
    return data

def main():
    data = create_data_model()

    # Create the mip solver with the SCIP backend.
    solver = pywraplp.Solver.CreateSolver('SCIP')

    # Variables
    # x[i, j] = 1 if item i is packed in bin j.
    x = {}
    for i in data['items']:
        for j in data['bins']:
            x[(i, j)] = solver.IntVar(0, 1, 'x_%i_%i' % (i, j))

    # y[i, j] = 1 if item i from owner j in bin.
    y = {}
    for i in data['owns']:
        for j in data['owners']:
            y[(i, j)] = solver.IntVar(0, 1, 'y_%i_%i' % (i, j))

    # Constraints
    # Each item can be in at most one bin.
    for i in data['items']:
        solver.Add(sum(x[i, j] for j in data['bins']) <= 1)
    # Each item can be at from one owner.
    # for i in data['items']:
    #     solver.Add(sum(y[i, j] for j in data['owners']) <= 1)
    # The amount packed in each bin cannot exceed its capacity.
    for j in data['bins']:
        solver.Add(
            sum(x[(i, j)] * data['weights'][i]
                for i in data['items']) <= data['bin_capacity'])

    # Objective
    objective = solver.Objective()

    for i in data['items']:
        for j in data['bins']:
            objective.SetCoefficient(x[(i, j)], data['values'][i])
    objective.SetMaximization()

    status = solver.Solve()

    if status == pywraplp.Solver.OPTIMAL:
        print('Total packed value:', objective.Value())
        total_weight = 0
        for j in data['bins']:
            bin_weight = 0
            bin_value = 0
            print('Bin ', j, '\n')
            for i in data['items']:
                if x[i, j].solution_value() > 0:
                    print('Item', i, '- weight:', data['weights'][i], ' value:',
                          data['values'][i])
                    bin_weight += data['weights'][i]
                    bin_value += data['values'][i]
            print('Packed bin weight:', bin_weight)
            print('Packed bin value:', bin_value)
            print()
            total_weight += bin_weight
        print('Total packed weight:', total_weight)
    else:
        print('The problem does not have an optimal solution.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: you should use the CP-SAT solver instead since you only have integer

Comment: I have values which could be floats. I just made it simpler for the example. Moreover, how would I integrate the owner constraint then?

Comment: What's the problem? Is there anything in your code besides copy-pasting some example?  Restricting the owner just means: `get unique values in data['owns'] with their indices (potential 1 to n mapping)`, `for each unique value, indices: add a constraint: sum(indices) <= 1` (indices assumed to link to binary vars deciding about knapsack-assignment)

Comment: `indices` is a set. not a scalar. With your simple example, the first constraint (out of 3) would look like: `sum([x[0, :].sum(), x[1, :].sum(), x[2, :].sum(), x[3, :].sum(), x[4, :].sum()]) <= 1`.  The `:` is there to sum over all the bins. Now how would the solver be able to pick from owner 1, who owns items 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 more than once? (No need for the y variable!)

Comment: If I only base on the item indice, how can I know if it is in the same group as others then?
For example, I can pick item 0 (w:48), mark it as picked so it won't be picked again but I don't see how to enforce when I pick it that the others with owner 1 won't be picked as well.
I agree that it is more or less the example code, I have not managed to add the owner constraint in it so far. I tried with the y varaible and commented out constraint declaration but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I would like to thank @sascha who provided the answer!

I attach below the code (I use 2 bins, 3 different owners):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from ortools.linear_solver import pywraplp


def create_data_model():
    """Create the data for the example."""
    data = {}
    weights = [48, 30, 42, 36, 36, 48, 42, 42, 36, 24, 30, 30, 42, 36, 36]
    values = [10, 30, 25, 50, 35, 30, 15, 40, 30, 35, 45, 10, 20, 30, 25]
    owns = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 1, 2]
    # owns = [0 for _ in range(len(weights))]
    data['weights'] = weights
    data['values'] = values
    data['owners'] = [0, 1, 2]
    data['owns'] = owns
    data['items'] = list(range(len(weights)))
    data['num_items'] = len(weights)
    data['bins'] = list(range(2))
    data['bin_capacities'] = [150, 100]
    return data

def main():
    data = create_data_model()

    # Create the mip solver with the SCIP backend.
    solver = pywraplp.Solver.CreateSolver('SCIP')

    # Variables
    # x[i, j] = 1 if item i is packed in bin j.
    x = {}
    for i in data['items']:
        for j in data['bins']:
            x[(i, j)] = solver.IntVar(0, 1, 'x_%i_%i' % (i, j))

    # Constraints
    # Each item can be in at most one bin.
    for i in data['items']:
        solver.Add(sum(x[i, j] for j in data['bins']) <= 1)

    # Each item can be at from one owner.
    for o in data['owners']:
        for j in data['bins']:
            owner = []
            for i in data['items']:
                if data['owns'][i] == o:
                    owner.append(x[i, j])
            solver.Add(sum(owner) <= 1)

    # The amount packed in each bin cannot exceed its capacity.
    for j in data['bins']:
        solver.Add(
            sum(x[(i, j)] * data['weights'][i]
                for i in data['items']) <= data['bin_capacities'][j])

    # Objective
    objective = solver.Objective()

    for i in data['items']:
        for j in data['bins']:
            objective.SetCoefficient(x[(i, j)], data['values'][i])
    objective.SetMaximization()

    status = solver.Solve()

    if status == pywraplp.Solver.OPTIMAL:
        print('Total packed value:', objective.Value())
        total_weight = 0
        for j in data['bins']:
            bin_weight = 0
            bin_value = 0
            print('Bin ', j, '\n')
            for i in data['items']:
                if x[i, j].solution_value() > 0:
                    print('Item', i, '- weight:', data['weights'][i],
                          ' value:', data['values'][i],
                          ' owner:', data['owns'][i])
                    bin_weight += data['weights'][i]
                    bin_value += data['values'][i]
            print('Packed bin weight:', bin_weight)
            print('Packed bin value:', bin_value)
            print()
            total_weight += bin_weight
        print('Total packed weight:', total_weight)
    else:
        print('The problem does not have an optimal solution.')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```